# rails error-- undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails development. This is my first app. And I've been struggling through it. Anyhow this is my issue. My modelname is PostIt and my controller is post_it_controller.rb

```
class PostItController < ApplicationController

def create
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @posts = Postit.create(params[:content])
 @posts.receiver_id = params[:content][:receiver_id]
 @posts.sender_id = current_user.id
end
```

and in my views I have this in create.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@posts) do |f| %>  
<%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, :value => @user %>  
<%= f.label :content %>  
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'inputbox' %>  
<%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn right' %>
<% end %>
```

the error I keep getting is undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in your code that break convention.

1. The `create` action is normally called when you submit the form with a `POST` request.
2. Your form should be rendered in a `new.html.erb` or `edit.html.erb`.
3. Your controllers should be named with the plural form. i.e. `PostItsController`.

With that said, I think the error is due to `@posts` being `nil`. This may be because `@posts` is being assigned in the wrong controller action, hence not being assigned at all by the time the response renders the form.

Comment: the controller actually is called PostsIts -- was just a typo typing it here since I was typing this up from a different device. But yeah, I'll definitely put it in the new action, but I don't really see how @posts is being assigned in the wrong controller action--it's under create and the form is on _create.html.erb.

Comment: `@posts` (or more correctly `@post`) should be assigned in the action that renders the form. `_create.html.erb` is not any part of the convention other than being a partial due to the leading underscore. In which case this is rendered with `<%= render 'posts/create' %>` somewhere in your template. If you will assign this variable in a `new` action, the form should be in `posts/new.html.erb` or at least render the partial that contains the form within `posts/new.html.erb`.